# Model contains interface property is not submitted to the controller in Web API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

In my Web API application, I have created a Model which has three property types of interface. Now from my client when I submitted the model it does not hit the controller method. If I open the network tab I found some errors. The request is Bad (400) request.

**Model**

```
public class CreateNewOrganizationModel : ICreateNewRegistrationDto
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} is required.")]
        public IOrganizationDetailDto OrganizationDetail { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} is required.")]
        public IList<IUserRoleDetailDto> UserRoleDetails { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} is required.")]
        public IPersonalDetailDto PersonalDetail { get; set; }
    }
```

**Network Tab error**

> {"errors":{"PersonalDetail.FirstName.PersonalDetail":["Could not
> create an instance of type CashFlow.Services.Dtos.IPersonalDetailDto.
> Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.
> Path 'PersonalDetail.FirstName', line 1, position
> 471."],"OrganizationDetail.OrganizationName.OrganizationDetail":["Could not create an instance of type
> CashFlow.Services.Dtos.IOrganizationDetailDto. Type is an interface or
> abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path
> 'OrganizationDetail.OrganizationName', line 1, position
> 42."],"UserRoleDetails[0].RoleName.0":["Could not create an instance of type CashFlow.Services.Dtos.IUserRoleDetailDto. Type is an
> interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path
> 'UserRoleDetails[0].RoleName', line 1, position
> 223."],"UserRoleDetails[1].RoleName.1":["Could not create an instance of type CashFlow.Services.Dtos.IUserRoleDetailDto. Type is an
> interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path
> 'UserRoleDetails[1].RoleName', line 1, position
> 266."],"UserRoleDetails[2].RoleName.2":["Could not create an instance of type CashFlow.Services.Dtos.IUserRoleDetailDto. Type is an
> interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path
> 'UserRoleDetails[2].RoleName', line 1, position
> 315."],"UserRoleDetails[3].RoleName.3":["Could not create an instance of type CashFlow.Services.Dtos.IUserRoleDetailDto. Type is an
> interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path
> 'UserRoleDetails[3].RoleName', line 1, position
> 364."],"UserRoleDetails[4].RoleName.4":["Could not create an instance of type CashFlow.Services.Dtos.IUserRoleDetailDto. Type is an
> interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path
> 'UserRoleDetails[4].RoleName', line 1, position
> 409."]},"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One
> or more validation errors
> occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|ed0f56a3-4be3d5ecfa7a80e4."}

Comment: Not sure, but with the error shown it seems you need to add Dto Class name instead of interface type for class properties. I have never used interface as a property.

Comment: What are the data you submit from the client look like? Could you pls show your controller method as well?